# ubuntu beginner install on windows

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7

new to the ubuntu world, so i would appreciate a little leniency with regards to my lack of knowledge or technical terms....

i currently have a windows 7 pc with 4 harddrives, 120gb internal ssd with windows, 120gb ssd for other stuff, and a 2tb backup hdd.  i have just bought the 4th harddrive which is a 128gb ssd to install ubuntu on.  i have searched google, youtube and the like to try to find answers, but i feel like i get inconsistent answers and solutions that appear to be right for me, but just a little bit different.

i want to do the most current version of ubuntu, and have it installed on the new 128gb harddrive and maintain windows on the 120gb.  i would also like an easy way to switch between the two os's, i'm guessing some kinda boot selector.

i'm sure i've left something out, but go easy on me, as i am a beginner with ubuntu

thanks in advanced for your help
jay

Comment: UEFI or Legacy BIOS Interface? Please use the [edit] button to add information to your question.